# Powershell convertto-json without labels

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-3.0

how to correctly convert a Powershell array of object properties to a json array of values, that is without the objects property lables in the array.

for example:
I want to make 2 json arrays for chart.js 
I will group some process objects:

```
$processgroup = get-process | group -property name

$processgroup.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                 
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                 
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array  

$chartlabels = $processgroup.name | convertto-json

$chartlabels

$chartlabels
[
    "ApMsgFwd",
    "ApntEx",
    "Apoint",
    "ApplicationFrameHost",
    "armsvc",
    "BtwRSupportService",
    "chrome",
    "com.docker.proxy",
    "com.docker.service",
    "concentr",
    "conhost",
    "csrss",
    "dllhost",
    "Docker for Windows",
    "dockerd",
    "dwm",
    "Everything",
    "EXCEL",
    "explorer",
    "fontdrvhost",
    "GROOVE",
    "hidfind",
    "HidMonitorSvc",
    "Idle",
    "iexplore",
    "IpOverUsbSvc",
    "jucheck",
    "jusched",
    "LicensingUI",
    "lsass",
    "mDNSResponder",
    "Memory Compression",
    "mqsvc",
    "MSASCuiL",
    "MsMpEng",
    "MSOIDSVC",
    "MSOIDSVCM",
    "MySQLNotifier",
    "NisSrv",
    "notepad",
    "notepad++",
    "nvSCPAPISvr",
    "nvvsvc",
    "nvwmi64",
    "nvxdsync",
    "OfficeClickToRun",
    "OneDrive",
    "OUTLOOK",
    "powershell",
    "powershell_ise",
    "prevhost",
    "Receiver",
    "redirector",
    "rundll32",
    "RuntimeBroker",
    "SearchIndexer",
    "SearchUI",
    "Secure System",
    "SecurityHealthService",
    "SelfServicePlugin",
    "services",
    "SettingSyncHost",
    "ShellExperienceHost",
    "sihost",
    "SkypeHost",
    "smss",
    "SMSvcHost",
    "spiceworks",
    "spiceworks-httpd",
    "spoolsv",
    "SppExtComObj",
    "sppsvc",
    "sqlwriter",
    "svchost",
    "System",
    "SystemSettings",
    "taskhostw",
    "TSVNCache",
    "vmcompute",
    "vmms",
    "vmnat",
    "vmnetdhcp",
    "vmware-authd",
    "vmware-tray",
    "vmware-usbarbitrator64",
    "wfcrun32",
    "wininit",
    "winlogon",
    "WINWORD",
    "WmiPrvSE",
    "WUDFHost"
]

#this is the array I want for charts labels, now for the chart value array

$chartvalues = $processgroup | select count | convertto-json

$chartvalues
[
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  30
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  5
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  4
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  30
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  75
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Count":  1
    }
]
```

how do I omit the "Count" label so PowerShell creates a single json array of the values only, as in the process name array.

I have tried

```
$chartvalues = $processgroup.count
```

results in the count of the number of groups

and I have tried

```
$chartvalues = $ processgroup | select count -expandproperty count | convertto-json
```

with the same result as above example

Answer (score 1):

You want a list, rather than object with key/value pair, so this should work*:

```
 $groups| foreach-object {$_.count}|convertto-json
```

When you do select after the pipeline it creates an object, thus pushes the object property name as well as the value as key/value pair into the json conversion process. 
i.e. If you have used select for name property, you would get the name/value pair in the json too...

```
 $groups| select-object name| convertto-json
```

*may be better solutions out there... but itworks..

Comment: Thanks Curios - nice to know!

Answer (score 1):

Silly me - I only needed to select and expand the property. like so.

```
$chartvalues = $processgroup | select -expandproperty count | convertto-json

$chartvalues
[
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    30,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    5,
    2,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    4,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    30,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    2,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    75,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    1,
    1
]
```

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do use the -ExpandProperty property of Select-Object to achieve your stated desire.  Is there any reason not to preserve the property->value notation which association inside of a single JSON array?  e.g.:

```
$processgroup = get-process | group -property name,count | select name,count | convertto-json
```

yields:

```
$processgroup
[
    {
        "Name":  "acevents",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "acrotray",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "AGSService",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "aiCOMMAPI",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "armsvc",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "audiodg",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "AuditManagerService",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "CcmExec",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "chrome",
        "Count":  9
    },
    {
        "Name":  "conhost",
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Name":  "csrss",
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Name":  "dllhost",
        "Count":  2
    },
    {
        "Name":  "dwm",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "explorer",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "Idle",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "lsass",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "lync",
        "Count":  1
    },
    {
        "Name":  "msdtc",
        "Count":  1
    }
]
```

Comment: the downvote police strike again without reason!! oh noes!

Comment: simply because -I guess- "count" values were required in the output, whereas your answer includes all...

Comment: That's kinda the entire point.  People downvote for ridiculous and unknown reasons when we're just trying to help the OP.  This was to show him that the kludgy nature of trying to associate two discrete arrays with associated values can be kept in much less confusing fashion and still achieve the desired goal and more accurate association.  If an item gets pushed or popped in either of his arrays.  $array1[nth] no longer corresponds to $array2[nth] without very special considerations whereas keeping them together bypasses that concern.